# How to have an item in ListView cover to whole screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I want to have a scrollable view that have fixed number of items. the first item should cover the parent container and than the user can scroll down to see the rest of the items.

I've tried to add Expanded to the first item but i get white screen

```
  ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: MainInfo(),),
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),    
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),  
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),  
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),   
    ],
  ),
```

Should i use ListView or SingleChildScrollView (didn't worked with Expanded also)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to accomplish that by using LayoutBuilder that return ListView

```
LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: MainInfo(),
          height: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
        Divider(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        MainInfo(),
        Divider(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        MainInfo(),
        Divider(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        MainInfo(),
        Divider(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        MainInfo(),
      ],
    );
  }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanded can't be used inside scrollable widgets. You can do something like this:

```
ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,child: MainInfo(),),
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),    
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),  
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),  
      Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.black,),    
      MainInfo(),   
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: what if i have a widget under the list view or an AppBar? setting the height to the height from MediaQuery will overflow the first item our of the screen. i edited the question as well to reduce confusion